# Adding data to the DOM after a request - Express, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, request

I looked at a few other questions and didnt get much traction for the issue I have at the moment.

I make a request to an api and get back 10 items as JSON. I display those items on the page with handlebars. I have a "load more" button at the bottom that needs to append 10 more items to the page.

In my Express server I make the request to the API and get the necessary data successfully.

This is what I've currently got:

```
request({
 url: url,
 qs : req.query,
 }, function(error, response, json) {

 return res.send(json.items)
 })
```

As some would point out, the `res.send()` kills it. I'm not sure how to append data to the previous JSON request, have that data handled by handlebars, all without the page reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Handlebare helper that returns a variable `data` to your template thats iterates on it (using `{{data}}`). The variable `data` can be a global Javascript variable to which you append content after calling your server for the second time.